# How to count elements in multidimensional array in php by their occurrence and quantity value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array and I was wondering how can I :

1. Sum qty so finaly I receive only unique products ids with their qty-s, for example:

product 805 - 1 piece
    product 1118 - 2+3+4 = 9pieces

```
array(2){
    ["product"]=> array(4){    
        [0]=> string(3) "805"     
        [1]=> string(4) "1118"     
        [2]=> string(4) "1118"     
        [3]=> string(4) "1118"     
    }     
    ["qty"]=> array(4) {      
        [0]=> string(1) "1"         
        [1]=> string(1) "2"     
        [2]=> string(1) "3"     
        [3]=> string(1) "4"     
    }    
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Use [foreach](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Are you getting this Array from the database? otherwise, I suggest you let MySQL (or whatever DB Engine you're using) solve it with a proper query.

Comment: no, this comes from post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$productQuantities = array();
$products = array("805","1118","1118","1118");
$quantities = array(1,2,3,4);
foreach($products AS $key=>$productId){
    $quantity = (int) $quantities[$key];
    if(isset($productQuantities[$productId])){
        $productQuantities[$productId] += $quantity;
    } else {
        $productQuantities[$productId] = $quantity;
    }
}

var_dump($productQuantities);
```

Comment: scragar I am getting error on this $productQuantities = []; why is that

Comment: scragar are you still here?

Comment: Just another stupid question : ) how to replace $products = array("805","1118","1118","1118"); with my $_post['product'] ids ? Itried this $products = array($_post['product']); and it returns errors

Comment: `$products = $_post['product'];`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$zipped=array_map(
    null, 
    $your_array['product'], 
    $your_array['qty']
);

$compact = array();

foreach ($zipped as $k => $v){

    if(!array_key_exists($v[0], $compact)){
        $compact[$v[0]] = $v[1];
    } else {
        $compact[$v[0]] += $v[1];
    }
}
```

Then you will find your result in $compact

Comment: Just a quick note, `array_key_exists` is about three times slower than `isset` for the same purpose, the only place to use array_key_exists over isset is where the value could be null(and it never can in this instance).